# Excel - In the summary table, I would like to return the outstanding amount (last column in picture) as at 31/12/2021, how do I do this?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an amortization table that looks as follows:

[image]

I would like to use a formula to find the outstanding amount as at 31/12/2021 but this is not a date that is in the table. Is there a way to condition INDEX and MATCH functions using the date as the limit?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try using CUMPRINC. The remaining loan value will be `100 000 000 - CUMPRINC(...)` with all of the variables filled in for CUMPRINC.

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Column F is the outstanding amount, you can do this with VLOOKUP using range lookup = TRUE rather than false. As long as your dates are sequential, using true tells VLOOKUP to take the closest match in an arranged list. With index match, you can also do this setting the match parameter to either -1 or 1, although you don't need to do index(match) on this particular problem.

```
=VLOOKUP(...link to your cell with the specified date here...,$C:$F,4,TRUE)
```